# How is it determined which memory block to use in c/c++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

**This is the code I wrote:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x[3] = {30,31,32}, y[3] = {40,41,42}, z[3] = {50,51,52};

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << *(x+i) << endl;
        cout << *(x-(3-i)) << endl;
        cout << *(x-(6-i)) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) { 
        cout << (long int)&x[i] << endl; // address of x
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << (long int)&y[i] << endl; // address of y
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << (long int)&z[i] << endl; // address of z
    }
}
```

**Here is the output:**

```
30
40
50
31
41
51
32
42
52

140701886846268
140701886846272
140701886846276

140701886846256
140701886846260
140701886846264

140701886846244
140701886846248
140701886846252
```

Here you can see the array which was declared at last takes the foremost memory address and second last takes memory address after the last one and so on.

Comment: That is up to the compiler. Why do you care? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You have **undefined behavior** in your program because you're going out of bounds of the array.

Comment: Do not assume `x[3]`, `y[3]`, and `z[3]` are connected together. Unless you declare them as a single array or `std::vector`

Comment: so it is not this case always? can be random too?

Comment: I wouldn't say it is random. Each compiler has a (non-trivial) implementation that will determine that. It can change based on the code being compiled, the compiler flags, compiler version, operating system, etc.

Comment: Stack frames are usually added downwards, so local variables will take the highest stack address first,

Comment: Not every variable ends up on the stack and alignment can create holes in the stack frame when adding variables to the stack frame. A decent compiler will place later variables in the holes left by earlier variables. It's also not unheard of for compilers to add variables in reverse order.

Comment: Try running the code on https://godbolt.org/z/5oseKbzGs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here you can see the array which was declared at last takes the foremost memory address and second last takes memory address after the last one and so on.

No, this is not what is happening. The program has **undefined behavior** because you're going out of bounds of the array for the expressions `*(x-(3-i))` and `*(x-(6-i))` for different values of `i`.

> Undefined behavior means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior. The program may just crash.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program. In your case this means that you have to make sure that you don't go out of bounds of the array.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>